events logs show the LOGOUT event as a Success, but the session between Cognito and Keycloak keeps active
I am trying to configure Cognito as an External IDP for my Keycloak, I´ve managed to configure it`s full login methods, etc.. but when it comes to logout it just wont work, the events logs show the LOGOUT event as a Success, but the session between Cognito and Keycloak keeps active
From my understanding this is not working because Cognito Logout endpoint is not using OAuth2 Standards, is that it?
I've tryed both methods described on Cognito docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html

As you suspect, your problems are caused by these limitations:

Keycloak is sending a standard end-session request which Cognito does not process.

If you do a new login and send a prompt=login parameter to Keycloak, and Keycloak forwards that parameter to Cognito, it is also ignored since Cognito does not support that parameter.



Cognito issues persistent SSO cookies which is another annoyance. Even if the user closes all browser windows as a workaround it does not solve the problem.

COMPLEX SOLUTION
There are many OAuth-like IDPs that do not fully follow standards, which can lead to this type of problem. The optimal way to resolve them is to develop an authorization server extension. More commonly this type of plugin is used for authentication, but might possibly be done for logout also.
This is the direction I would investigate, Maybe start by looking into how to implement custom authentication using the Keycloak SDK, then see if a logout extension is possible. It would work like this:

Set a cookie with context like the post logout redirect URI.
Redirect to Cognito using a custom logout request, using a Keycloak post logout redirect URI.
Process the response from Cognito, read context and expire the temporary cookie.

